# Is it correct to judiciously construct a quantifier tableau to yield a desired falsification of a formula, yet the rules to apply weren't exhausted?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, beth-tableau

I am a beginner in logic, which I am learning on my own. I am aware of the fact that a quantifier tableau with open branches doesn’t always show the formula under consideration is falsified- unless there are no more rules to apply.

Consider the following statement: *Anyone who can solve all logic problems is a good student. No student can solve every logic problem. Therefore, there are logic problems that no student can solve.*

If we let $Ex:$ $x$ is a student, $Gx:$ $x$ is good, and $Lxy:$ $x$ solves problem $y$ the statement is translated into the formula:

$$\bigg[\Big(\forall x\big((\forall y Lxy)\Rightarrow(Ex\wedge Gx)\big)\Big)\wedge\Big(\forall x\big((\forall y Lxy)\Rightarrow\neg Ex\big)\Big)\bigg]\Rightarrow\Big[\exists y\big(\forall x (Lxy\Rightarrow \neg Ex)\big)\Big]$$

Now, intuitively I can see that we can falsify the formula if we have two students, two problems, and one student solves problem 1 but not 2 while the other solves problem 2 but not 1.

Below is my attempt at a using a tableau to obtain the desired falsification.
\begin{matrix}
& & & T\;\forall x((\forall y Lxy)\Rightarrow(Ex\wedge Gx))& \\
& & & T\;\forall x((\forall y Lxy)\Rightarrow\neg Ex)& \\
& & & F\;\exists y(\forall x (Lxy\Rightarrow \neg Ex))\;(1)& \\
& & & F\;\forall x(Lxp\Rightarrow\neg Ex)\;(2)& \\
& & & F\;Lap\Rightarrow\neg Ea& \\
& & & \boldsymbol{T\;Lap}& \\
& & & F\;\neg Ea& \\
& & & \boldsymbol{T\; Ea}& \\
& & & T\;(\forall y Lay)\Rightarrow\neg Ea& \\
& F\;\forall y Lay& & & T\;\neg Ea\\
& \boldsymbol{F\; Laq}\; (3)& & & F\;Ea\\
& F\;\forall x(Lxq\Rightarrow\neg Ex)\; (4)& & & \rm{\bf{X}}\\
& F\;Lbq\Rightarrow\neg Eb\; (5)& & & \\
& \boldsymbol{T\; Lbq}& & &\\
& F\;\neg Eb& & &\\
& \boldsymbol{T\; Eb}& & &\\
& T\;(\forall y Lby)\Rightarrow\neg Eb& & &\\
F\;\forall y Lby& & T\;\neg Eb& & \\
\boldsymbol{F\; Lbp}\; (6)& & F\; Eb& &\\
& & \rm{\bf{X}}& & & &\\
\end{matrix}

(2)  is an instantiation of (1) for $y=p$, and because we do not want the branch to close we need a new problem $q\neq p$ in (3).
(4) is an instantiation of (1) for $y=q$, and we need a new student $b\neq a$ in (5) so that the branch does not close.
Finally, in (6), in order for the branch not to close we need a new problem $r\neq q$. But if we assume that there are exactly two students and exactly two problems, then $r$ must be $p$.

Hence, the open branch provides the desired falsification of the formula (in bold): Both $a$ and $b$ are students. Student $a$ solves problem $p$ and does not solve problem $q$, while student $b$ solves problem $q$ but not problem $p$.

Am I correctly using the Tableau method in order to produce a falsification of the formula? What concerns me is that although I can read off a valuation falsifying the formula, there are still rules to be applied. On the other hand, applying them does not affect the fact that I already can read that valuation.

Hence, if one judiciously constructs a tableau so that a valuation falsifying the formula under consideration can be read from an open branch, does it matter if there are still rules to apply? I suspect not, since if the valuation which can be read falsifies the formula under consideration that means the rules left to apply have no impact on the truth/falsity of the formula.

Edit: I just noticed that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347813/standard-method-of-solution-to-predicate-logic-word-problem-with-tableaux-method) question is related to the same statement, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct: as soon as you have found one valuation which falsifies the formula, then you know it is falsifiable. Your formula is also satisfiable (e.g., if there is just one problem that no-one can solve), so you wouldn't expect every branch in the tableau to close.

Comment: It is certainly satisfiable. For example, the structure $M$ with domain $U_{M}\{a,p\}$ and relations $E_{M}=\{<a>\}$, $G_{M}=\emptyset$, and $M_{L}=\emptyset$ satisfies the formula. I'll just add that the structure $M$ falsifying the formula obtained by the tableau above has domain $U_{M}=\{a,b,p,q\}$, and relations $E_{M}=\{<a>,<b>\}$, $G_{M}=\emptyset$, and $L_{M}=\{<a,p>, <b,q>\}$.